# how to add a ModulePassManager in llvm pass?

Tags: clang, llvm

I'm trying to add a ModulePassManager in llvm pass, because all pass is function pass, so all I added createModuleToFunctionPassAdaptor function, but compile error, I don't know how to solve it. does anybody know how to solve this problem. I tried this:

```
llvm::PreservedAnalyses DBogusFlow::run(llvm::Module &M,
                                        llvm::ModuleAnalysisManager &MAM) {
  bool Changed = runOnModule(M);

  auto MPM = std::make_unique<ModulePassManager>();

  MPM->addPass(createModuleToFunctionPassAdaptor(createAggressiveDCEPass()));
  MPM->addPass(
      createModuleToFunctionPassAdaptor(createInstructionCombiningPass()));
  MPM->addPass(
      createModuleToFunctionPassAdaptor(createCFGSimplificationPass()));
  MPM->run(M, MAM);

  return (Changed ? llvm::PreservedAnalyses::none()
                  : llvm::PreservedAnalyses::all());
}
```

below is the compile error

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DBogusFlow.dir/lib/DBogusFlow.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/llvm/IR/PassManager.h:48,
                 from /home/v4kst1z/Desktop/ollvm-deobfuscator/lib/../include/DBogusFlow.h:12,
                 from /home/v4kst1z/Desktop/ollvm-deobfuscator/lib/DBogusFlow.cpp:9:
/usr/include/llvm/IR/PassManagerInternal.h: In instantiation of ‘PreservedAnalysesT llvm::detail::PassModel<IRUnitT, PassT, PreservedAnalysesT, AnalysisManagerT, ExtraArgTs>::run(IRUnitT&, AnalysisManagerT&, ExtraArgTs ...) [with IRUnitT = llvm::Function; PassT = llvm::FunctionPass*; PreservedAnalysesT = llvm::PreservedAnalyses; AnalysisManagerT = llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function>; ExtraArgTs = {}]’:
/usr/include/llvm/IR/PassManagerInternal.h:83:22:   required from here
/usr/include/llvm/IR/PassManagerInternal.h:85:17: error: request for member ‘run’ in ‘((llvm::detail::PassModel<llvm::Function, llvm::FunctionPass*, llvm::PreservedAnalyses, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function> >*)this)->llvm::detail::PassModel<llvm::Function, llvm::FunctionPass*, llvm::PreservedAnalyses, llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function> >::Pass’, which is of pointer type ‘llvm::FunctionPass*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
   85 |     return Pass.run(IR, AM, ExtraArgs...);
      |            ~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/llvm/IR/PassManagerInternal.h: In instantiation of ‘llvm::StringRef llvm::detail::PassModel<IRUnitT, PassT, PreservedAnalysesT, AnalysisManagerT, ExtraArgTs>::name() const [with IRUnitT = llvm::Function; PassT = llvm::FunctionPass*; PreservedAnalysesT = llvm::PreservedAnalyses; AnalysisManagerT = llvm::AnalysisManager<llvm::Function>; ExtraArgTs = {}]’:
/usr/include/llvm/IR/PassManagerInternal.h:88:13:   required from here
/usr/include/llvm/IR/PassManagerInternal.h:88:55: error: ‘name’ is not a member of ‘llvm::FunctionPass*’
   88 |   StringRef name() const override { return PassT::name(); }
      |                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~^~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/DBogusFlow.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/DBogusFlow.dir/lib/DBogusFlow.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:86: CMakeFiles/DBogusFlow.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Comment: The error message says: /usr/include/llvm/IR/PassManagerInternal.h:85:17: error: request for member ‘run’ in … (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)

Comment: @arnt Can you be more specific? I still don't understand

Comment: If you look at column 15 of line 87, you find a ".". The error message suggests that you meant to use "->" instead of ".", which is a common typo.